# whats the difference between custom DNS and FQDN

Tags: networking

what is the difference between custom DNS and FQDN, i got this question in my mind when i was using certificate generation for our servers. what is the difference it makes if we use FQDN or custom DNS for generating CSR.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your server has the hostname 'anne'.

And lets say that you bought a domain called 'hathaway.com'.

Then yout FQDN is 'anne.hathaway.com'.

The FQDN is the combination of the hostname of the server + the domain.

If you generate a cert for your FQDN it will not reach all the subdomains of your domain.

Comment: this is incomplete - a FQDN should include the trailing "." that represents the root label, unless being used in the context of a protocol that explicitly requires complete domain names (and are thus implicitly FQDNs).

Comment: Sorry to ask, but could you explain this a little better? I know that when we use it on local environments we could use something like "machine.local" as the FQDN. But I didn't understand very well your comment.

Comment: `.local` is an exception, since it's not really DNS at all, and will usually get handed off the mDNS (aka Bonjour).